# What viewer supports multiple different formats?

Tags: libreoffice, gimp, blender, image-viewers

I am currently trying to make a Linux distro, that will primarily be used to recover, backup, restore, scan Mac/Windows/Linux machines. When I recover data, it's hard to tell if the images(and or other file) is defective, because, Ubuntu doesn't support all of the exotic files in the world.

I am trying to make this as slim a distro as possible, so if I can find a viewer that supports allot(or all?) image/video/doc etc... formats out there, then I don't have to install GIMP, Blender, LibreOffice to read Adobe PhotoShop, Autodesk Maya, Microsoft Office files.

Also, if I just need to install the libraries/codes, to view the files with `eog`(or other), then please list the libraries/codes I need.

Comment: All formats for what? You will very likely not find a tool capable of viewing documents, images, audio/video/... file classes. Even viewers for "all" image formats are probably not existing. I would bet you won't even find any website listing "all" image formats.

Comment: @ByteCommander `all(or allot of)`. Don't need all of them, although that would be great. I am trying to keep my distro as slim as possible. So, few viewers in stead of gimp, blender, LibreOffice would be great. I could save so much space.

Comment: Isn't ImageMagick pretty versatile? VLC for multimedia stuff (audio/video). Not sure if there is any document viewer smaller and more versatile than LibreOffice though.

Comment: @ByteCommander With media, you can't go wrong with VLC. LibreOffice, documents. eog, images. I was hoping I could just install a viewer and install the libraries/codes needed to view documents, media, images files.

Comment: like [gloobus-preview](http://gloobus.net/gloobus-preview/), support some files, install a library, and it can then also preview `doc(x)` files.

Comment: You don’t need to view to back up, nor do you need to view, to check file integrity.  what you are asking for is difficult to provide, especially on a file by file basis. If you had a previous image, or checksum, then it would be easy. If you had a compressed folder, or disk image, it would be do able.  Corruption can be a wide range of things some corrupted files are still readable, or identifiable, others are  garbage.  take this image, its technically improperly formatted with the addition characters. But it still viewable. Corrupt? not Corrupt? http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/m.png